# How do you read a string (json or similar) into a data table into mysql or oracle sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

What would you call the following string (json or other format)? How do you read the following string into oracle sql or mysql as a data table?

```
{"headers": {"Employee": ["Id", "Month", "Salary"]}, "rows": {"Employee": [[1, 1, 20], [2, 1, 20], [1, 2, 30], [2, 2, 30], [3,2,40],[1,3,40], [3,3,60],[1,4,60],[3,4,70]]}}
```

expected table:

```
| Id | Month | Salary |
|----|-------|--------|
| 1  | 1     | 20     |
| 2  | 1     | 20     |
| 1  | 2     | 30     |
| 2  | 2     | 30     |
| 3  | 2     | 40     |
| 1  | 3     | 40     |
| 3  | 3     | 60     |
| 1  | 4     | 60     |
| 3  | 4     | 70     |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According [this article](https://mysqlserverteam.com/import-json-to-mysql-made-easy-with-the-mysql-shell/), `MySQL Shell 8.0.13 (GA)` introduced a feature which enable you import JSON files into MySQL. Before previous version, you will need a script to parse JSON files to data which can insert to tables in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, but the article you posted is mainly about **importing** a file of json. I asked about **reading** in a json-formatted string and made it as a data table.